# Filter Key from a hashmap Map<String, List<String>> when a string matches one of the elements in the list

Tags: java, spring

I'm fairly new to java in general so help is very appreciated.

I have a structure like this:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> campaign = new Hashmap<>();
```

This hashmap has values like this:

```
campaign = {   
   "John": {["1234"]},
   "Doe": {["5555","2222"]},
   "Smith": {["Smith"]}
}
```

I'm trying to filter the key of this hashMap when one of the elements matches an element of the list.

I've tried this so far based on similar solutions I found:

```
public String getKey(String id) {
    campaign.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getValue().stream().
    anymatch(list -> list.contains(id)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue() ))
}
// I see toMap is not what I need but don't know what to use
```

I expecto to get: `getKey(1234) = "John"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `findAny()`:

```java
public String getKey(String id) {
    return campaign
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(map -> map
            .getValue()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(list -> list.contains(id))
        )
        .map(Entry::getKey) 
        .findAny()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

`anyMatch()` returns an `Optional` that contains any value of the (filtered) `Stream` (if it is present).

If you want to get the first element in the `Stream`, you could use `findFirst` instead but order is not relevant in most `Map`s anyways.

With `.map`, you can map the entry to its key.

In case you want to return all keys, you could use methods like `toList` or `.toSet`.

With `orElse(null)`, you specify that `null` should be used if no matching entry/key was found.

As an alternatives to `orElse`, you could return the `Optional` or use `orElseThrow` if the value needs to be present.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to collect to a map, but to the key(s) you found.

```
.filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains(id)) 
.map(Entry::getKey) 
.collect(toSet());
```

You might find more than one key, hence the `Set`.